# How to exclude parts of a JS program from testing to avoid coverage reduction?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I got this test:

[image]

Every column of this test is green, except for those 2 in yellow. When seeing the file, the reason why it has low scoring is because this function `Async Wrapper`:

[image]

Is there a way to exclude it from the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Jest docs](https://codewithhugo.com/jest-exclude-coverage/)

> Jest uses istanbul under the hood to calculate coverage. Mostly Jest abstracts this from the end user, all you have to do in your application is call jest --coverage (and configured the appropriate coverage configuration fields). The fact that istanbul is used internally does show, for example, the documentation for coverageReporters mentions that “Any istanbul reporter can be used.”, which shows what’s actually collecting coverage data and generating the reports.

Here is an example:

```
function ignoreLine() {
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  console.log(
    'This line won\'t appear as uncovered'
    );
}
```